# cURL CURLOPT_POST to an HTML form based on angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, curl

I try to fill in an HTML form via cURL. Normally, I'd pass variables according to their corresponding form equivalent. E.g.

```
<input name='prename'>
```

But the remote form has been created with angularJS and therefore the input field has no name attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="your prename" ng-model="prename" force-selection="true" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }">
```

So, this won't work:

```
function curlStart($domain, $var = false)
{
    global $sCurlResult;

    $fp = curl_init($domain);

    curl_setopt($fp,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($fp,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($fp,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    if($var != false)
    {
        curl_setopt($fp,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt ($fp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var); 
    }

    $sCurlResult = curl_exec($fp);

    if(curl_errno($fp) != 0)
    {
        $send = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $send = TRUE;
    }

    curl_close($fp);

    return $send;
}

$formURL = 'https://urlofremoteform';
$var = 'prename=John;

$send = curlStart($formURL,$var);
```

How can I pass the value "John" to the input field for prename?